# How can I batch-process images to adjust contrast in terminal?

Tags: command-line, image-processing

I've scanned 200+ pages.  I am wondering if it is possible to touch these up by running a batch command line image software with a contrast manipulation option.  Essentially I am wanting to give a command such as:

```
image_software *.JPG --contrast -1
```

The pages I scanned have content on both sides.  The smallest amount of the content from the reverse side is showing in the scanned image.  It is like a watermark --- online annoying.

What software + command might work for what I am describing?

Comment: I suspect you might be after the `-brightness-contrast` of imagemagick combined with a `for` loop. Some details here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#brightness-contrast Let me know if this is something like what you are after?

Comment: @andrew.46 Yes this is what I am wanting to do.  Perhaps a reduction by 10

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One excellent option is to use ImageMagick's `-brightness-contrast` option in combination with a bash `for` loop.

To see how it all works first find a test image and experiment with the following syntax:

```
convert -brightness-contrast 10x5 input.jpg output.jpg
```

The `-brightness-contrast` option has 2 elements:

1. `-brightness`. In the example above this has been set at 10 and possible settings are from -100 to +100. Positive values *increase* the brightness while negative values *decrease* the brightness. Using a '0' value means that the brightness will remain unchanged.
2. `-contrast`. In the example above this has been set at 5 and again possible settings are from -100 to +100. Positive values *increase* the contrast while negative values *decrease* the contrast. Using a '0' value means that the contrast will remain unchanged.

Once you have found the settings best for your image you can navigate to the folder holding your images and run a bash `for` loop:

```
for j in *.jpg
do 
  convert -brightness-contrast 10x5 "$j" altered_"$j"
done
```

Here you can see I have made a small naming alteration for the *output file* which you can of course tailor to your specific needs.

There are many different ways to accomplish your goal with ImageMagick but this would be my own choice as it is both the easiest to use and to understand :).

**References:**

- [ImageMagick -brightness-contrast](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#brightness-contrast): All of the details on this command from the ImageMagick web site.

Comment: Is there a command which would allow me to rotate images by degrees?  Such as 5 degrees left or 3 degrees right?

Comment: @RonPiggott Indeed there is :). Trying experimenting with `convert -rotate xxx` command. I  have not ever used this but I beieve the integer (where I have placed 'xxx') can be either negative or positive. This could possibly be a new question rather than a continuation of this question? Check for duplicates first though!

Comment: The syntax given doesn't work with the Windows version - correct syntax would be: `convert "infile.jpg" -brightness-contrast 10x5 "outfile.jpg"`.  Whether the operand order has been altered in the Ubuntu build I have no idea, but it would make no sense to have the Windows and Ubuntu versions different.